# how we can display an active thumbnail in color when this one is active with AngularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In this project, I have 4 pictures at the top of the web page, they are my thumbnails. When I click on one of this picture I want it to appear in color, and this color stays on the picture until we click on an other picture. During this time the others pictures are in black and white.
I did this exercise with AngularJS, and I don't know where I can put this kind of property in my code, can you help me please?

The picture of want I want to obtain for the project :
[image: picture of the project]

The code of the project :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img ng-click="changeName1()" ng-src="{{firstname1}}"  >
    <img ng-click="changeName2()" ng-src="{{firstname2}}" >
    <img ng-click="changeName3()"ng-src="{{firstname3}}" >
    <img ng-click="changeName4()"ng-src="{{firstname4}}" >
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
    <div class="backgroundpicture">
        <img ng-src="{{src}}">
    </div>
    <div class="foregroundpicture">
        <img ng-src="{{src2}}">
    </div>   
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname1 = "photoshop-logo.jpg";
    $scope.firstname2 = "autocad-logo.png";
    $scope.firstname3 = "counterstrike-logo.png";
    $scope.firstname4 = "leagueoflegends-logo.jpg";


    $scope.src = "photoshop-screenshot.png";
    $scope.src2 = "photoshop-profile.PNG";
    $scope.title = "Photoshop";
    $scope.firstnamedisplay =$scope.firstname1;

    $scope.changeName1 = function() {
        $scope.firstnamedisplay =$scope.firstname1;
        $scope.src = "photoshop-screenshot.png";
        $scope.src2 = "photoshop-profile.PNG";
        $scope.title = "Photoshop";

    }
    $scope.changeName2 = function() {
        $scope.firstnamedisplay =$scope.firstname2;
        $scope.src = "autocad-screenshot.png" ;
        $scope.src2 = "autocad-profile.png";
        $scope.title = "Autocad";

    }
    $scope.changeName3 = function() {
        $scope.firstnamedisplay =$scope.firstname3;
        $scope.src = "counterstrike-screenshot.jpg";
        $scope.src2 = "counterstrike-profile.png";
        $scope.title = "Counter-Strike";

    }
    $scope.changeName4 = function() {
        $scope.firstnamedisplay =$scope.firstname4;
        $scope.src = "leagueoflegends-screenshot.png";
        $scope.src2 = "leagueoflegends-profile.png";
        $scope.title = "League of legends";

    }

});
</script>

</body>
</html>

    body {
    margin: 5%;
}

.thumbnail>img{
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
}

.backgroundpicture >img {
    padding-top: 7%;
    z-index:1;
    width: 90%;

}

.foregroundpicture >img  {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 55%;
    left:40%;
    top:65%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, you'll want to use the CSS property `filter: grayscale(100%)` to make your thumbnails appear without color. There's numerous ways to implement this with the same end result, but here is a link to a js fiddle that demonstrates the concept: 
https://jsfiddle.net/s3pLef9c/47/

**To Explain what is happening in the JS Fiddle:**
Basically this demo is using the `ng-click` directive to add an `.image-active` class to an element with a base class of `.image`.
 Here is what those classes look like:

```
.image{
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 8px solid #2c2c2f;
  background-color: #FEC10D; // change this to background-image or add an <img> tag inside the <div> tag and remove this line!
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.image-active{
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

The base class of `.image` is using `filter: grayscale(100%)` to initially set the images to have no color. The `.image-active` class is added to the element when the click event happens, overriding the grayscale filter to `filter: grayscale(0%) and adding color. Then existing`.image-active` class is removed.

I wasn't sure based on your question if you wanted the first image to be active by default, or if you wanted them all gray to start, so I took a liberty there but I'm happy to update that for you.

Note: This example isn't using images, just `<div>` tags with background colors applied. But if you simply remove the color and add in your background images then it should work for you.

**To Explain Further:**
It's much easier and faster to add/remove a CSS property or class than it is to swap out an image source file based on application state. This gets even easier when using the `ng-repeat` and `ng-class` directives provided by angular, here is a link to the documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, there's an even more 'Angular' way to execute this idea that I feel I should provide. the `$scope.images` array in the fiddle is comprised of objects with a key `active: true or false`.  Instead of adding and removing the classes with jQuery as demonstrated in the fiddle, you should loop through the `$scope.images` array and set that key to be true or false depending on which element needs the `.image-active` class. The `ng-class` directive provided in the fiddle would recognize the change in scope and update the classes for you.